# Pandas Aggregating a GroupBy object using UDF

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that I have the following. I group by "happy" and then sum over each group. It works great.

```
import pandas as pd
testdf = pd.DataFrame({"happy": [1, 2, 1, 3], "sad": [4, 5, 6, 7], \
                      "cool":[1, 99, 0, -5]})
testgb = testdf.groupby(["happy"])
testgb.sum()
```

But what if I want to use my own function that takes in a list of values and returns a number INSTEAD of sum(); like

```
def my_max(ilist):
    return max(ilist)
testgb.my_max()
```

In this case the output should be:

```
happy   sad    cool
1       6      1
2       5      99
3       7      -5
```

Does anyone know how to do it? I read how to use your own function for grouping by but not for accumulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to pass the list of values from other column, e.g. `sad`. You can use the `agg` function

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame({"happy": [1, 2, 1, 3], "sad": [4, 5, 6, 7], "cool":[1, 99, 0, -5]})
testgb = testdf.groupby(["happy"]).agg({'sad': lambda x: max(x)})
```

Of course there are probably built-in procedures to accomplish what you have in mind but since you pose a hypothetical scenario, it's hard to say more.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've added the output to my example for reference. Your example works and can be extended to mine pretty easily, so I'm accepting this answer.